# recover space after dropping user in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, drop

I have virtualbox with oracle database. So, I had 5 gb space left. I tried to import 2gb something dmp file, and it failed after disk became full. So, I tried to drop it by using "DROP USER ABC";
The username was dropped but the space was not recovered.
Please let me know I would  be able recover this space?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the "CASCADE" option? If the user dropped without that option, then it didn't own any database objects and would not have recovered any space. There are other ways you could have lost the space, too, besides from the data itself: archived transaction logs, space for indexes (that don't store data in the dmp files), and the growth of the TEMP tablespace come immediately to mind.

Use the DBA_SEGMENTS view to establish which objects are actually taking up space in your database, which users own them, and which tablespaces they're located in:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_SEGMENTS.html
- http://dba-oracle.com/t_dba_segments.htm

Also check your archivelog location, automatic diagnostic repository (ADR) for log and trace file growth, and see if you can reduce the size of your TEMP tablespace (if it seems to have grown).